# UISearchController - search bar disappears from wrapper on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uisearchcontroller

Seems like a common iOS bug but I've tried every solution I can find and have seen no results.

I am creating a `UISearchController` and adding it to a `UIView` wrapper like this:

```
self.searchController = [[SearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

[self.searchBarWrapper addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

The problem is that whenever the search bar is touched, the keyboard pops up, but the whole search bar disappears.

I looked at these posts:

- [My UISearchBar in UISearchController disappear when I start searching. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458336/my-uisearchbar-in-uisearchcontroller-disappear-when-i-start-searching-why)
- [iOS 9 searchBar disappears from table header view when UISearchController is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687240/ios-9-searchbar-disappears-from-table-header-view-when-uisearchcontroller-is-act)
- [UISearchController searchBar disappears on first click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341494/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-disappears-on-first-click)
- [Disappearing UISearchController in a TableViewController that is in a UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755541/disappearing-uisearchcontroller-in-a-tableviewcontroller-that-is-in-a-uinavigati)
- [UITableView disappears when UISearchController is active and a new tab is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032798/uitableview-disappears-when-uisearchcontroller-is-active-and-a-new-tab-is-select)
- [Search Bar disappears after tap on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683193/search-bar-disappears-after-tap-on-it)
- [UISearchController searchBar in tableHeaderView animating out of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222671/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-in-tableheaderview-animating-out-of-the-screen)
- [search bar getting disappeared in ios UIsearchcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494192/search-bar-getting-disappeared-in-ios-uisearchcontroller)
- [Search Bar disappeared from view while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633176/search-bar-disappeared-from-view-while-typing)

and tried every solution, ultimately adding this initialization code:

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
self.navigationController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
self.navigationController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

and these delegate functions

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
  // definitely runs, if I put a breakpoint here it stops
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
  [self.searchBarWrapper addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
  searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
}
```

But the search bar still disappears when touched. What else can I try?

I think the difference between my code and the rest of the posts is that I'm using a `UIViewController` created programmatically without a XIB. There is a `UITableView` child view, but it doesn't interact directly with the search bar. There is no `UINavigationBar`, the search bar is at the top of the view.

UPDATE:

This is my view hierarchy relative to the search bar:

```
- UIViewController 
 - UIView
  - UIScrollView
   - UIViewController
    - UIView
     - UISearchBar
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I would suggest.

1. in viewDidLoad

   ```
   // after creating the searchController add
   self.mySearchController.active = YES;

   // also add this for the search bar
   [self.mySearchController.searchBar setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
   ```

I set up a simple test app. Added a UIView to the top  (this will be the searchBarWrapper). Constrained top, leading, trailing and gave it a fixed height. Added a tableView below that, with a prototypeCell and constrained it Top,Leading,Trailing,Bottom --- plain simple nothing out of the ordinary. All works just fine.

i can post the whole viewControllerClass if you need it.

Comment: didn't work for me, but maybe its due to something in my view hierarchy. I updated the question with it

Comment: Ahh, yes that would have been helpful to know from the outset. There is a bug in which UISearchController does not properly handle the case where the view of the view controller presenting the UISearchController is inset from its superview. This may be part of the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem. What fixed it for me was adding anchors to the searchBarWrapper, then adding them again in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Basically I had to add them twice:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarWrapper: UIView!
fileprivate var searchController: UISearchController!

//MARK:- View Controller Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setSearchController()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        positionSearchControllerInWrapperView()
}

//MARK:- Custom Funcs
fileprivate func setSearchController(){
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search man..."
        searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        definesPresentationContext = true
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

        positionSearchControllerInWrapperView()
}

//this gets called TWICE
fileprivate func positionSearchControllerInWrapperView(){
        searchBarWrapper.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
        searchController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchController.searchBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBarWrapper.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        searchController.searchBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBarWrapper.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        searchController.searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBarWrapper.topAnchor).isActive = true
        searchController.searchBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBarWrapper.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are still seeking for a solution, just create a wrapper view and subview your searchbar to it:

```
UIView *searchWrapperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0, 0, screenWidth, 44}];
[self.view addSubview:searchWrapperView];
[searchWrapperView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
```